# d3.js : Want to understand the concept of applying individual properties to elements via a single command

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So yesterday I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142209/d3-js-applying-styles-to-individual-lines/22143359#22143359), the answer of which gave me some useful insight into how powerful d3's functions can be.

But when trying to apply it myself, it produced strange results. I'm trying to replace the circles of the [patent suits](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) example with various icons, but even though `console.log` shows that the function is receiving the paths and names of all images correctly, it ends up with just one icon for all nodes. Besides that, I'm surprised to see so many `console.log` outputs when I have just six nodes.
[image]
The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#linkup {
  fill: green;
}

.link.linkup {
  stroke: green;
}

.link.unknownlink {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var links = [
  {source: "Device1",  target: "Device20", type: "linkup", icon: "images/workstation.jpg"},
  {source: "Device1",  target: "Device5",  type: "linkup", icon: "images/router.jpg"},
  {source: "Device2",  target: "Device8",  type: "linkdown", icon: "images/workstation.jpg"},
  {source: "Device3",  target: "Device8",  type: "linkdown", icon: "images/workstation.jpg"}
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960, height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))//prolly giving values to the nodes
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["linkdown", "linkup", "unknownlink"])
    .enter().append("marker")//arrowmarker type of markers
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")//the viewing area for every marker I guess...
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");//this is for the arrow

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())//console.log(force.links());//outputs [Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkup"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkup"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="unknownlink"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}, Object { source={...}, target={...}, type="linkdown"}]
    .enter().append("path")//add a standard svg path
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })//this is where the linestyle is applied
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });//this is where the arrow end style is applied

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .call(force.drag); //assigning the capability of dragging the circle

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text") //adding the svg text element
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; }); //getting the name from nodes which was assigned to force

circle.selectAll("image")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {console.log(d.icon);return d.icon;})
    //.attr("xlink:href", "images/workstation.jpg")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);

circle.on("mousedown", function(d) { d.fixed = true; });//make the node sticky
circle.on("dblclick", function(d) { d.fixed = false; });//make the node un-sticky

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
function transform(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }
</script>
```

**My question:** ...is not just about what am I doing wrong in `.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {console.log(d.icon);return d.icon;}`. My question is also that I want to properly understand how this selection works. How is it that `selectAll("text")` and `.enter().append("text")` was able to append every individual piece of text, but my image attachment didn't work properly? How exactly do these `data()`, `enter()` and `selectAll()` functions manage to do this job of selecting object instances individually and applying properties to them?

Comment: Did you mean to pass `force.nodes()` to your `selectAll` for the images instead of `links`?

Comment: No that's not it. `force.nodes()` was the first thing I had tried (it ends up displaying a graph with links but no images on the nodes). I thought it might be because I'm not adding `link.icon` in `links.forEach`, but adding `link.icon` caused even the working example (screenshot I posted) to end up without any image on the nodes.

Comment: Right, I see. I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here -- you're using the images for the nodes, so they should be properties of the nodes, not the links. You were also binding the data again and appending as many images as there were links to each node group (hence the many messages). I've fixed this in http://jsfiddle.net/xPGkg/ -- is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh perfect! It worked! Thank you so much. Please do post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Am intrigued by how you achieved this. Will be going thru the code.

Comment: Right, I've got to get some shopping done before everything is closed, but I'll write up an answer with some more detailed explanation in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing more messages than you're expecting and not the right images because you're in fact appending many more elements than you think. The key parts of the code are these:

```
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")

circle.selectAll("image")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("image")
```

After the first block of code, `circles` holds a selection that contains all the newly appended `g` elements -- that is, one for each node. By doing a `.selectAll(...).data(...)` on this selection, you're making a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) -- for *each element in the selection* you're selecting descendant elements and binding data. So for each `g` element, you're binding data to all its descendant `image` elements. The subselection is per element of the original selection, not for the original selection as a whole.

As a result, you're appending, to each `g` element, `links.length` `image` element. This is because you're binding `links` as the data. So all `g` elements had the same `image` elements in the same order (as the same data was bound to each), but only the first is shown in SVG.

To fix this, I've done two things. First, as the images are for the nodes and not the links, I've modified your code to generate the nodes from the links slightly to include the information which icon to use in the nodes.

To actually append the images, you don't need another selection, the following code does it.

```
circle.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {console.log(d.icon);return d.icon;})
```

This is telling D3 to append a new `image` element to each element in the current selection (i.e. the new `g` elements).

Comment: Was helpful to learn about nesting. Did a diff of the code to see the changes. If you don't mind, I'm also curious about the line `link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, icon: link.icon});`. Does it mean "assign `nodes[link.source]` to `link.source` if the page is refreshed and the value is already available else create `nodes[link.source]` with the value of `{name: link.source, icon: link.icon}`"?

Comment: Yes -- the only change to before is that there's an `icon` attribute now so that you can use the node data for the images.