# change a solid link to a particular node into dashed one programmatically in d3

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, svg

#### Graph Type

**Radial Tidy Tree**

#### Current Output

Initially I start with a JSON response from the server and do a recursion to make the JSON flat and use `d3.tree` to plot the figure shown below.

I have programmed the `Legislation` node such that on double click it will send some information to the backend and obtain a new JSON which requires the graph to be rerendered.
[image: Current1]

Upon rerendering the node will change to `Manufacturer/Legislation` as shown below:
[image: Rerendered]

As in the picture, I wish to make that particular link `strokedashed` to indicate that particular node has been changed.

#### code

For brevity I will trim out the code here:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const self = this;
        const svg = d3.select('svg'),
            width = +svg.attr('width'),
            height = +svg.attr('height'),
            g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 3 + 240) + ',' + (height / 3 + 140) + ')');

        const tree = d3.tree()
            .size([2 * Math.PI, 375])
            .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });
        const root = tree(d3.hierarchy(this.parse_node(this.config['viewStructure'])));
        this.root = root; // store this is private variable
        const link = g.selectAll('.link')
            .data(root.links())
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .attr('d', <any>d3.linkRadial()
                .angle(function(d) { return d['x']; })
                .radius(function(d) { return d['y']; }));

        const node = g.selectAll('.node')
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', function(d) { return 'node' + (d.children ? ' node--internal' : ' node--leaf'); })
            .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + radialPoint(d.x, d.y) + ')'; })
            .on('click', click)
            .on('dblclick', dblclick);

        node.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 5)
            .style('fill', (d) => {
                if (d.data['color'] === 'green') {
                    return '#0f0';
                } else {
                    if (d.depth === 0) {
                        return '#999';
                    }
                    return '#f00';
                }
            });

        node.append('text')
            .attr('dy', '0.31em')
            .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? 6 : -6; })
            .attr('text-anchor', function(d) { return d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? 'start' : 'end'; })
            .attr('transform', function(d) {
                return 'rotate(' + (d.x < Math.PI ? d.x - Math.PI / 2 : d.x + Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + ')'; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.data['name']; });


        function radialPoint(x, y) {
            return [(y = +y) * Math.cos(x -= Math.PI / 2), y * Math.sin(x)];
        }

     // For brevity removed the click and double click logic..
    }
```

**Rerendering function**

```
getProperties() {
  // .... Some logic
  const self = this;
  function askExtension() {
            // call the backend, get the json response
            // rerender with some latency here..
            setTimeout(() => {
                d3.selectAll('svg > *').remove();
                self.ngAfterViewInit();
                console.log(nodeInfo.parent.data.name + '/' + nodeInfo.data.name); // `Manufacturer/Legislation`

               // I can use self.root here to find the node 
               // how do I get the link information here and change
              
            }, 1000);
        }
}
```

I tried using `.forEach()` to loop through the `self.root.descendants()`, find `Manufacturer/Legislation`, and use the `.links()` function but that does not serve my purpose.

How do I programmatically make the particular link to be dashed, post-rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use a style function like you are using for node color.

Essentially, when you merge nodes, set the class or some attribute that allows you to differentiate it. Then you can set the style conditionally.

```
link.style('stroke-dasharray', function(d){ if(d.data['someprop'] === 'valueForMerged'){
  return ("10,3");
}
else{
  return undefined;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142209/d3-js-applying-styles-to-individual-lines) article explains it further.

Also, [this site](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/making-dashed-line-in-d3js.html) explains stroke-dasharray. Essentially, the dasharray format is "# pixels on, # pixels off".

Comment: Woah! fantastic. As a test case I tried: `link.style('stroke-dasharray', function(d) {if (d['target']['data']['name'] === 'Manufacturer/Legislation' {return ('10,3');} else {return undefined;}}` and it works perfect. I am looking for some parameter that could make this process automatic.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you are looking for a generalized test to find changed branches?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am looking for. I am currently using name of the current node + name of the immediate parent node as a check to see if there is a mergedNode in the graph